# Time and attendance

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, report

I have a table with below data

```
EMPID   |  DEVICE     |    EVENTTIME
-----------------------------------------
112     |  READ_IN    |    2018-11-02 07:00:00.000
112     |  READ_IN    |    2018-11-02 08:00:00.000
112     |  READ_OUT   |    2018-11-02 12:00:00.000
112     |  READ_IN    |    2018-11-02 13:00:00.000
112     |  READ_OUT   |    2018-11-02 16:00:00.000
```

I need a select query to achieve below data:

```
ID_Emp  |Date          |TimeIn |TimeOut|Hours
```

---

```
112     |02/11/2018    |8:00   |16:00  |7:00
```

In my table, the employee came at 7:00 but he didn't do his work then after one hour he came back and work. He took his lunch break at 12:00-13:00 and left his work at 16:00. So his total working hours will be 7 hours.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle ?

Comment: And can there be consecutive 'read_out's. If so, what happens then?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to eliminate time between 12 and 1, I wrote simple where clause for this. After that 
I used PIVOT for transposing rows to columns by max EVENTTIME.
And finally, I wrote outermost SELECT query for converting columns to your intended format.

here is the fiddler link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f1189/10

here is the code:

```
SELECT 
  EMPID, 
  TO_CHAR(READ_IN, 'HH24:MI') READ_IN, 
  TO_CHAR(READ_OUT, 'HH24:MI') READ_OUT, 
  EXTRACT(HOUR FROM READ_OUT - READ_IN) HOUR
FROM (
  select * from (
    select  * from Table1
    WHERE 
      extract(hour from eventtime) not between '12' and '13'
  )
  PIVOT (
    MAX(EVENTTIME) 
    for DEVICE in ( 'READ_IN' READ_IN, 'READ_OUT' READ_OUT )
  )
)
```

please note that this example only works for oracle.